# Pagination for multiple search fields results laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel, search, eloquent, pagination, laravel-blade

I have just started with Laravel and I am trying to make a multiple search function with proper pagination. The function works for the first page but on page two or three for example it doesn't. I think it's not giving the results to the next page but I can't seem to find an answer.

---

this is my search function inside ClientController:

```
public function search(Request $request)
{
    $clients = Client::
    when($request->nom, function ($query) use ($request) {
        $query->where('nom', 'like', $request->nom);
    })
        ->when($request->prenom, function ($query) use ($request) {
            $query->where('prenom', 'like', $request->prenom);
        })
        ->when($request->date_debut, function ($query) use ($request) {
            $query->where('date_naissance', '>=', $request->date_debut);
        })
        ->when($request->date_fin, function ($query) use ($request) {
            $query->where('date_naissance', '<=', $request->date_fin);
        })
        ->when($request->active, function ($query) use ($request) {
            $query->where('active', '=', $request->active);
        })
        ->paginate(10);

    return view('client.find', ['clients' => $clients]);
}
```

This is my route:

```
Route::get('search', 'ClientController@find');
Route::post('search', 'ClientController@search')->name('searchpost');
```

this is how I show my pagination in find.blade.php:

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
             @if(!empty($clients))
                 {{ $clients->links() }}
             @endif
        </div>
    </div>
```

this is the URL of page two:

```
/search?page=2
```

Answer (score 2):

First I changed my route to:

```
Route::get('search', 'ClientController@search')->name('search');
```

And my view to:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
         @if(!empty($clients))
             {{ $clients->appends(request()->except('page'))->links() }}
         @endif
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
->paginate(10)->appends($request);
```